# Rails partial dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4

My table has a release_date column that saves in the format

> 2002-02-01

In the model I have

```
validates_date :release_date, :allow_blank => true
```

In my new view I have the following

```
<%= f.label :release_date, class: "control-label" %>
              <%= f.date_select :release_date, :start_year => Date.current.year, :end_year => 1970, :include_blank => true %>
```

With gives three separate drop downs for selecting a date.

What I want is for a partial date to be selectable when a user only knows the year, or the month and the year. I thought this might work with the appropriate allow_blank tags in but it doesn't Currently if you select and month and year but leave the day blank it doesn't save the date to the db at all.

How can I allow for partial dates? Preferably saving with the same format as currently used so that my existing data isn't invalid.

In my show view I call release_date with this

```
<%= @miniature.release_date.strftime("%d %b %Y") unless @miniature.release_date.blank? %>
```

I would like to be able to display the whole date when available and if not have it appear as

> Feb 2002

or just

> 2002

where that is all that's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your `release_date` should be a `date` column, it means that a full-date is required for creating record even only the year or year+month are given.

You may need an integer column, `date_mask` for example, to tell which parts(year, month, day) are available and modify the `create` action in your controller to store `date_mask` information.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def create
    #...
    if params[:my_model][:"release_date(2i)"] == ''
      # no month is given, insert fake month and day
      params[:my_model][:"release_date(2i)"] = '1'
      params[:my_model][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 4 # 100
    elsif params[:my_model][:"release_date(3i)"] == ''
      # no day is given, insert a fake day
      params[:my_model][:"release_date(3i)"] = '1'
      mask = 6 # 110
    else
      # full-date
      mask = 7 # 111
    end
    # ...
    MyModel.create(my_model_params.merge(date_mask: mask))
    # ...
  end

  private

  def my_model_params
    params.require(:my_model).permit(:release_date, :date_mask)
  end
end
```

In your model, create a method `release_date_display` to show the date according `release_date` and `date_mask`

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  def release_date_display
    if self.date_mask == 4
      return self.release_date.strftime('%Y')
    elsif self.date_mask == 6
      return self.release_date.strftime('%b %Y')
    else
      return self.release_date.strftime('%F')
    end
  end
  #...
end
```

For existing data, just insert 7 in your `data_mask` column.

**UPDATE:**

An example to handle partial date: https://github.com/sibevin/partial-date-app

Comment: That looks excellent. Just implementing it. Shall I make my date_mask column have a default of "7" or would that cause problems and I should just insert the "7" for existing lines?

Comment: Actually I would use 0 as the default value, it means the `release_date` is not be set up yet. It may be more suitable to express the initial status. Note that you should also handle 0 mask in `release_date_display` in this case.

Comment: The create action is not adding the date_mask. All my new entries are appearing with date_mask "0". I'm guessing this is because I'm locked into using my-model.new(my_model_params) and @my_model.save rather than a create and so I'm not passing the "date_mask: mask" bit of your code. Where can I put that in a new/save rather than create?

Comment: the release_date_display is working great. with 4, 6 and 7 when I enter them manually. It seems to currently treat 0 date_masks the same as 7. What would you suggest adding to handle the 0 mask differently?

Comment: For your first question, it seems something is wrong with the strong parameter. Make sure `date_mask` is in the permit of `my_model_params`. Or try to use an assignment `my_model.date_mask = mask` before `my_model.save`.

Comment: In my opinion, 0 `date_mask` is for a _nil_ `release_date`, and 7 is  for a valid full `release_date`. So `release_date_display` should return an empty string or nil when `data_mask` is equal to 0.

Comment: Okay, I have date_mask in the permit of my_model_params. I tried it with the assignment and now it does pass the date_mask but the release_date is blank unless you enter a full release_date. I thought this might be due to my validates_date but removing that has not solved the problem. I guess the insert fake month/day code is not working?

Comment: I just write a simple example(source: https://github.com/sibevin/partial-date-app) and it seems to work well... Maybe you can show your example and see what I can help.

Comment: I've looked at your example and have got it working. My problem now is I can EDIT the date but I cannot get the edit form to show the blank for day or month because 1 is inserted. I need my form select to use date_mask to display blank as the selected option in the drop downs. Any idea how?

Comment: An interesting question, I find `date_select` has an option `selected` to assign the default value of a date, but only accept `nil` or a `Date` object. I trace the rails source and finally find a way to solve it. The key point is that `Date` object cannot support partial date, so I use a struct to fake a Date class which provides year, month and day. See the updated example. ;-)

Comment: Amazing. Quite a good little challenge this has thrown up. That works perfectly. Well done, a really clever solution. So pleased. Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some gems out there to deal with this use case:

https://github.com/58bits/partial-date (this one uses a single column)

The other ones tend to use multiple columns:

https://github.com/gnapse/incomplete_date

https://github.com/alexreisner/flex_date

You'll also find more information in this SO thread: [How would I store a date that can be partial (i.e. just the year, maybe the month too) and output it later with the same specifity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90246/how-would-i-store-a-date-that-can-be-partial-i-e-just-the-year-maybe-the-mont)

Comment: Neither of those gems seem the right fit for my problem and that SO thread is recommending something along the lines of Sibevin Wang's answer below but more vague. I'll go with Sibevin Wang's answer if I can get it to work but thanks for the answer.

Comment: A benefit to use an existing gem is that it is easier to use and more consistent if you have many partial dates used in several models. My answer is only a special case to handle the single date column.

Comment: BTW, the existing gems are also good examples to see how other people solve this problem.